# Impala 2.11 :AnalysisException: Subqueries are not supported in the select list

Tags: sql, select, subquery, impala

Need to select min(eff_dt) and max(exp_dt) per group.
A group is defined by columns C1 and C2 : for each distinct couple (C1,C2) , i need to have the min(eff_dt) and max(exp_dt).
A simple group by wont help here , because it does not work in case of "lag" in the time : If a record will have same values of  (c1,c2) but not in a row, result will be omitting the in between lag

Here is an example of input, desired output and output by using only group by ...

```
--INPUT                              --DESIRED OUTPUT                     --OUTPUT of SIMPLE GROUP BY
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
C1  C2  EFF_DT      EXP_DT           C1   C2  Eff_dt      EXP_DT          C1   C2  EFF_DT       EXP_DT
4   8   2013-11-30  2014-01-22       4    8   2013-11-30  2014-01-22      4    8   2013-11-30   2999-12-31
2   8   2014-01-23  2014-01-23       2    8   2014-01-23  2014-01-23      2    8   2014-01-23   2014-01-23
4   8   2014-01-24  2015-12-31       4    8   2014-01-24  2999-12-31
4   8   2016-01-01  2016-12-31
4   8   2017-01-01  2018-03-15
4   8   2018-03-16  2018-07-24
4   8   2018-07-25  2999-12-31
```

Tried to use a subquery inside select statement to select max(exp_dt) based on current row but didnt work as impala does not support that .....

Here is the query i tried , which is working fine but not in Impala

```
SELECT    
     T0.C1,
     T0.C2,
     MIN(T0.EFF_DT) AS MIN_EFF_DT,
     T0.EXP_DT
FROM (
    SELECT 
    T1.C1,
    T1.C2,
    T1.EFF_DT,
    (
        SELECT MAX(T2.EXP_DT)
        FROM (select * from TABLE_NAME ) T2
        WHERE T2.C1 = T1.C1
        AND   T2.C2 = T1.C2
        AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 FROM (select * from TABLE_NAME) T3
            WHERE T3.EXP_DT < T2.EXP_DT 
            AND   T3.EXP_DT > T1.EXP_DT
            AND  (T3.C1 <> T2.C1 OR T3.C2 <> T2.C2 )
        )

    ) EXP_DT
    FROM (select * from TABLE_NAME) T1
) T0 
GROUP BY 
T0.C1,
T0.C2,
T0.EXP_DT
ORDER BY MIN_EFF_DT ASC
```

Comment: And your query?

Answer (score 0):

This is a gap-and-islands problem.  A difference of row numbers is one approach:

```
select c1, c2, min(eff_dt), max(exp_dt)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by eff_dt) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by c1, c2 order by eff_dt) as seqnum_1
      from t
     ) t
group by c1, c2, (seqnum - seqnum_1);
```

Why this works is a little tricky to explain.  I find that if you look at the results in the subquery, you will see how the difference between the values identifies adjacent rows with the same `c1`/`c2` values.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. It works just fine on a very small subset of the data i have. When i run it against the full table ( ~500M rows, with the couple (C1,C2) being a larger set of columns (C1,C2,...,C8) it takes forever ...without any result ....

Comment: @SnowWhite . . . I would recommend that you ask *another* question, with a clear description that is closer to the data you are really working with -- and the scale of the problem.  I can think of different solutions, but I don't know which is applicable.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58940019/how-to-solve-a-gap-and-islands-problem-with-a-high-volume-set-of-data-in-impala