# How to solve a gap-and-islands problem with a high volume set of data in Impala

Tags: sql, impala

Have a Type 2 Dimension residing in an Impala table with ~500M rows having 102 columns : ( C1, C2, ..., C8,...C100, Eff_DT, EXP_DT)
Need to select only the rows that have distinct combination value of (C1,C2,..,C8).
For each selected record, the EFF_DT and EXP_DT must be respectively the min(eff_dt) and max(eff_dt) of the group to which that record belongs ( a group here is defined by a distinct combination (C1,C2,..,C8)

A simple Group By will not solve the problem here because it will omit the time lags for the same group ...

For the sake of simplicity, here is what is required and what i have tried - assuming that only 2 columns are defining a group (not 8 )
Here is an example of input, desired output and output by using only group by ...

```
--INPUT                              --DESIRED OUTPUT                     --OUTPUT of SIMPLE GROUP BY
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
C1  C2  EFF_DT      EXP_DT           C1   C2  Eff_dt      EXP_DT          C1   C2  EFF_DT       EXP_DT
4   8   2013-11-30  2014-01-22       4    8   2013-11-30  2014-01-22      4    8   2013-11-30   2999-12-31
2   8   2014-01-23  2014-01-23       2    8   2014-01-23  2014-01-23      2    8   2014-01-23   2014-01-23
4   8   2014-01-24  2015-12-31       4    8   2014-01-24  2999-12-31
4   8   2016-01-01  2016-12-31
4   8   2017-01-01  2018-03-15
4   8   2018-03-16  2018-07-24
4   8   2018-07-25  2999-12-31
```

Tried to use a subquery inside select statement to select max(exp_dt) based on current row but didnt work as impala does not support that .....

Here is the query i tried , which is working fine but not in Impala (Because subqueries are not supported inside select statements

```
SELECT    
     T0.C1,
     T0.C2,
     MIN(T0.EFF_DT) AS MIN_EFF_DT,
     T0.EXP_DT
FROM (
    SELECT 
    T1.C1,
    T1.C2,
    T1.EFF_DT,
    (
        SELECT MAX(T2.EXP_DT)
        FROM (select * from TABLE_NAME ) T2
        WHERE T2.C1 = T1.C1
        AND   T2.C2 = T1.C2
        AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 FROM (select * from TABLE_NAME) T3
            WHERE T3.EXP_DT < T2.EXP_DT 
            AND   T3.EXP_DT > T1.EXP_DT
            AND  (T3.C1 <> T2.C1 OR T3.C2 <> T2.C2 )
        )

    ) EXP_DT
    FROM (select * from TABLE_NAME) T1
) T0 
GROUP BY 
T0.C1,
T0.C2,
T0.EXP_DT
ORDER BY MIN_EFF_DT ASC
```

Comment: I'm a little confused.  Your rows appear to be tiling on one or more dimensions.  What columns define the "tiling" (that is, where the next eff date comes following and end date)?  And which define the data columns?

Comment: The columns that define the segregation are C1,C2,C3,...,C8 
I ll phrase the problem :
In a type 2 Dimension, every time any column is changed , there is a new record that is created for the same id , with the new value(s) and new eff_dt and exp_dt
In my case, i am not interested to have all those records.I am only interested to have the records that were resulting from teh change of one of the 8 columns C1,...C2 ...

Comment: .... C8
The solution you suggested works exactly as expected but have one issue : Does not work on high volume, with many Columns ( instead of just C1..C2 )

Comment: . . I doubt that you have 500,000,000 rows with non-overlapping effective and end dates -- the time spans involved would probably be only a few seconds at most.

Comment: Yes - There is overlapping eff and exp dates . The time spans is roughly in the days ( the table is covering data from 2013, some of which is still active ...)

Comment: . . You are not answering the question.  I assume that the effective and end dates are "tiling" time for some dimension(s) -- say, the status of a given customer.  Two different customers are not related to each other.

Comment: Correct. Each record have an id column. The table has n rows for each id , i need to extract only m records with m<= n for each id ( based on the unique C1,c2,..,c8 combination AND the CONSECUTIVENESS over time : a unique combination (c1,c2,..,c8) might appear 2 times if there is a time lag between first and second time it occured

Comment: Ooh sorry - i went back to your first question : the column defining the tiling is a column called "id" , and then you have the 8 columns that will form the segregation , and the eff-dt and exp_dt

Answer (score 0):

In all likelihood, the previous solution will work when modified for the `id` column:

```
select id, c1, c2, min(eff_dt), max(exp_dt)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by eff_dt) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by id, c1, c2 order by eff_dt) as seqnum_1
      from t
     ) t
group by id, c1, c2, (seqnum - seqnum_1);
```

You should be able to expand the number of columns as you with.

Comment: This worked as expected only when there is no gaps in the original data ( means all (eff_dt,exp_dt) are consecutive over time with no wholes ... when there is a whole (means from x to y where nothing happens, in other words if you have a row with exp_dt = date_x and the next row have eff_dt = date_x+y days ( y >1 day) ...

Comment: @SnowWhite . . . That is how the data looks in this question.  If you have a *different* question, I would suggest that you ask it as a *new* question and be clear about the data anomalies.